# Cannot resolve method `values()` for Enum inside the Generic method

Tags: java, generics, enums, generic-method

I am trying to build a *generic method* which gets an `enum` as an argument and processes some information.

But unfortunately, it doesn't work as I would like. Maybe you have some suggestions to improve my code and prevent the errors.

```
private static ProductSearchColumnRange extractAllColumnRangeFromEnum(ProductSearchColumn column,
                                                                      Enum someEnum) {
    return ProductSearchColumnRange.builder()
            .column(column)
            .range(Arrays.stream(someEnum.values())
                    .map(element  -> new RangeOption(element.getValue(), element.name()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .build();
}
```

I get the following error on the `someEnum.values()` call:

> Cannot resolve method `values()` in `Enum`

I get the following errors on the `element.getValue()` and `element.name()` calls:

> Cannot resolve method `getValue()`

> Cannot resolve method `name()`

The *enums* I need to use in the method `extractAllColumnRangeFromEnum()` above all have the same structure.

For example, one of them look like this:

```
public enum DeploymentModelType {
   PRIVATE("Private"),
   HYBRID("Hybrid"),
   PUBLIC("Public");

   String value;

   DeploymentModelType(String value) {
       this.value = value;
   }

   public String getValue() {
       return value;
   }
}
```

I know that I can prevent the error by using

```
private static ProductSearchColumnRange extractAllColumnRangeFromEnum(ProductSearchColumn column,
                                                                      DeploymentModelType someEnum) { 
... 
}
```

But then my method would not be generic. I want to use this method for *any of my enums*.

Comment: Not every Enum has the method `getValue` so if you define your method as taking any enum you'll not be able to use that method. Is introducing an Interface that contains the `getValue` method and that all your enums implement an option?

Answer (score 4):

Since you need all the `enum` elements to generate a list of `RangeOption` objects, your method should expect as a parameter a `Class<T>` of the enum, not a single element.

In order to access the *enum constants*, you can make use of the static method [`EnumSet.allOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html#allOf(java.lang.Class)) of the `EnumSet`. Which expects the enums `Class<T>` as parameter.

In order to be able to invoke your custom method `getValue()` you need to introduce an *interface*, let's say `ModelType`, that will declare that method. In turn, `DeploymentModelType` and other *enums* should implement this *interface*.

And you need to add a ***generic type parameter*** to the declaration of your method. It needs to be placed after *modifiers* (*if any*) and before the *return type* of the method.

In this case, *generic type parameter* has to be `<T extends Enum<T> & ModelType>`. I.e. `T` is a subtype of both `java.lang.Enum` class and `ModelType` interface.

[*for information on the syntax of generic methods, take a look at this tutorial*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html)

The code might look like that:

```
private static <T extends Enum<T> & ModelType>
               ProductSearchColumnRange 
               extractAllColumnRangeFromEnum(ProductSearchColumn column,
                                             Class<T> enumClass) {
    
    return ProductSearchColumnRange.builder()
        .column(column)
        .range(EnumSet.allOf(enumClass).stream()
            .map(element  -> new RangeOption(element.getValue(), element.name()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .build();
}

public enum DeploymentModelType implements ModelType {
    // your code
}

public interface ModelType {
    String getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the `java.lang.Enum` don't have `values()` method, this method is implicitly declared by compiler. It's mean that `values()` method only exist in `MyEnum.class`, can't found in `MyEnum.java`.

More info about implicitly declared method and enum specifications can be found in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9